# Errors when fetching vote count and submitting comment

Tags: support, error-message

Why am I getting following error messages frequently?

[image]
[image]

Comment: May be your Internet connect slow or javascript issue.

Comment: Or maybe the question was deleted?

Comment: I am getting same issue from long. It because of JavaScript issue or may be slow internet.. I don't know how to solve it. SO, i just refresh and vote.

Comment: These errors can also been seen when there are DNS issues (like DOS attacks) going on in the internet neighbourhood, perhaps affecting your ISP rather than your individual connection.